# Is Matlab incorrect for mnrfit?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

It seems Matlab is giving incorrect results for multinomial logistic regression.

In their example documentation using Fisher's Iris dataset  [[link]](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mnrfit.html), they give coefficients for the model which can be used on the same data set itself to get the modeled probabilities.

```
load fisheriris
sp = categorical(species);
[B,dev,stats] = mnrfit(meas,sp);
PHAT=mnrval(B,meas);
```

However, none of the expected value aggregates match the population aggregates which is a requirement for a MaxEnt classifer (See slide 35  [[here]](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~smaskey/CS6998/slides/statnlp_week6.pdf), or Eq 14  [[here]](http://www.win-vector.com/dfiles/LogisticRegressionMaxEnt.pdf), or Agresti "Categorical Data Analysis" pg 298, etc.)

For example

```
>> sum(PHAT)
>>   49.9828   49.8715   50.1456
```

should all equal 50 (population values), likewise for other aggregations

If the parameters

```
B=[36.9450   42.6378
   12.2641    2.4653
   14.4401    6.6809
  -30.5885   -9.4294
  -39.3232  -18.2862]
```

were used instead then all aggregated sufficient statistics match.

Additionally it seems odd that Matlab is solving it with likelihoods, which can produce an error,

> Warning: Maximum likelihood estimation did not converge. Iteration
>   limit exceeded. You may need to merge categories to increase observed
>   counts

where the only requirement, proved by MLE consideration, is that the expected values match and no likelihood evaluation is needed.

It would be a nice feature that if instead of true classes are given we can give an option for including just the aggregate information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submitted a technical error review within Mathworks website. Their reply:

> Hello [----],
>
> I am writing in reference to your Technical Support Case #01820504
>   regarding 'mnrfit'.
>
> Thanks a lot for your patience and reporting this issue. This appears
>   to be unexpected behavior. It appears to be related to an existing
>   issue we have in our records, that "mnrfit" does not give correct
>   maximum likelihood estimates in certain cases. Since the "mnrfit"
>   function is not finding the maximum likelihood estimates for the
>   coefficients, we calculated the actual MLEs. When we use these
>   estimates, we get the desired result of all 50s in this case.
>
> The issue is that, for this particular dataset in our example, the
>   classes can be separated perfectly. This means that the logistic
>   function, in order to get exact zero or one probabilities, needs to
>   have infinite coefficients. The "mnrfit" function carries out an
>   iterative procedure with the coefficients getting larger, but it stops
>   at a point where the results have the issue that you have found. We
>   certainly agree that "mnrfit" could be made to do better. Our
>   development team is working on it.
>
> At this stage, I am not able to suggest a workaround other than to
>   write a custom implementation as my colleague and I had tried. For
>   now, I will be closing this request as I have already forwarded it to
>   our records. However, if you have any additional questions related to
>   this case, please do not hesitate to reach me.
>
> Sincerely,
>   [----]
>    MathWorks Technical Support Department

Comment: Portion of email from 7/20/17: Our records indicate that on March 7, 2016, you contacted technical support regarding MATLAB 8.3 (R2014a). The topic of the issue was:
"Multinomial logistic regression fit (mnrfit) is not giving correct results" We are pleased to inform you that this issue has been addressed in Release R2016b.